# Utilize a function-based index to precompute columns, while also selecting non-indexed columns

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle18c, oracle-spatial

**Test data:**

```
create table lines (id number(38,0), 
                    details1 varchar2(10), 
                    details2 varchar2(10), 
                    details3 varchar2(10), 
                    shape sdo_geometry);
begin
    insert into lines (id, details1, details2, details3, shape) values (1, 'a', 'b', 'c', sdo_geometry(2002, 26917, null, sdo_elem_info_array(1, 2, 1), sdo_ordinate_array(574360, 4767080, 574200, 4766980)));
    insert into lines (id, details1, details2, details3, shape) values (2, 'a', 'b', 'c', sdo_geometry(2002, 26917, null, sdo_elem_info_array(1, 2, 1), sdo_ordinate_array(573650, 4769050, 573580, 4768870)));
    insert into lines (id, details1, details2, details3, shape) values (3, 'a', 'b', 'c', sdo_geometry(2002, 26917, null, sdo_elem_info_array(1, 2, 1), sdo_ordinate_array(574290, 4767090, 574200, 4767070)));
    insert into lines (id, details1, details2, details3, shape) values (4, 'a', 'b', 'c', sdo_geometry(2002, 26917, null, sdo_elem_info_array(1, 2, 1), sdo_ordinate_array(571430, 4768160, 571260, 4768040)));
    ...
end;
/
```

Full test data here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=54b801d20acc23d65d9e0d3dd3738c93)

---

I want to pre-compute calculated columns via a function-based index.

**Steps:**

**(1)** Create functions to get the startpoint X & startpoint Y coordinates (numbers) from the SDO_GEOMETRY column :

```
create function startpoint_x(shape in sdo_geometry) return number 
deterministic is
begin
    return shape.sdo_ordinates(1);
end; 
   
create function startpoint_y(shape in sdo_geometry) return number 
deterministic is
begin
    return shape.sdo_ordinates(2);
end;  

select
    id,
    details1,
    details2,
    details3,
    startpoint_x(shape) as startpoint_x,
    startpoint_y(shape) as startpoint_y
from
    lines

        ID DETAILS1   DETAILS2   DETAILS3   STARTPOINT_X STARTPOINT_Y
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------ ------------
       177 a          b          c                574660      4766400
       178 a          b          c                574840      4765370
       179 a          b          c                573410      4768570
       180 a          b          c                573000      4767330
       ...

[full table scan]
```

**(2)** Create a FBI that stores the ID, startpoint X, and startpoint Y in a composite index:

```
create index lines_fbi_idx on lines (id, startpoint_x(shape), startpoint_y(shape))
```

**(3)** When I only select the indexed columns, the FBI gets invoked (no full table scan), which is good:

```
select
    id,
    startpoint_x(shape) as startpoint_x,
    startpoint_y(shape) as startpoint_y
from
    lines
where --https://stackoverflow.com/a/59581129/5576771
  id is not null
  and startpoint_x(shape) is not null
  and startpoint_y(shape) is not null

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |               |     3 |   117 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| LINES_FBI_IDX |     3 |   117 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                --------------
   1 - filter("ID" IS NOT NULL AND "INFRASTR"."STARTPOINT_X"("SHAPE") IS NOT 
              NULL AND "INFRASTR"."STARTPOINT_Y"("SHAPE") IS NOT NULL)
 
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

That works as expected.

*Note: That's just a bare-bones example for the purposes of this
post. In reality, the custom functions would have more complicated
logic and be a lot slower — hence the need for precomputing in an
index.*

---

**Question:**

In addition to selecting the indexed columns (`ID`, `startpoint_x`, and `startpoint_y`), I also want to select the non-indexed columns: `details1`,`details2`, and `details3`.

How can I utilize the function-based index for the precomputed columns, while also selecting the non-indexed columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can do it by simply:

1. Selecting only the indexed columns.
2. Joining to the non-indexed columns.

---

```
select
    a.id,
    a.startpoint_x,
    a.startpoint_y,
    b.details1,
    b.details2,
    b.details3
from
    (
    select
        id,
        startpoint_x(shape) as startpoint_x,
        startpoint_y(shape) as startpoint_y
    from
        lines
    where --https://stackoverflow.com/a/59581129/5576771
      id is not null
      and startpoint_x(shape) is not null
      and startpoint_y(shape) is not null
    ) a
left join
    lines b
    on a.id = b.id

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |               |     3 |   219 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS OUTER                  |               |     3 |   219 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN               | LINES_FBI_IDX |     3 |   117 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| LINES         |     1 |    34 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | LINES_FBI_IDX |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                --------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter("INFRASTR"."STARTPOINT_X"("SHAPE") IS NOT NULL AND 
              "INFRASTR"."STARTPOINT_Y"("SHAPE") IS NOT NULL AND "ID" IS NOT NULL)
   4 - access("ID"="B"."ID"(+))
 
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

I had incorrectly assumed that it would be more complicated than that. I thought I might need to ***force*** Oracle to invoke the FBI when selecting the indexed columns, while also doing a table scan to get the unindexed columns. I wondered if some sort of materialized hint would be needed. But it looks like the join did what I want without needing a hint.

---

In general, the benefit of this overall non-spatial FBI solution is:

It works around a limitation with function-based **spatial** indexes:

> From @DavidLapp of Oracle
>
> A spatial index is invoked only by the WHERE clause, not the SELECT list.
>
> [Utilize function-based spatial index in SELECT list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72535550/5576771)

Whereas my non-spatial FBI doesn’t have that problem. It can be invoked by the SELECT list, [as long as there are `IS NOT NULLs` in the where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59581129/5576771).

Next step:

> In theory, maybe the resulting numeric XY columns could be
> "spatialized" after-the-fact:
>
> A) Convert the XY to SDO_GEOMETRY on-the-fly / after-the-fact in a
> query.
>
> or B) Use GIS software to display the XYs as points in the map — using
> a dynamic "layer" in the application. For example, use ArcGIS Pro's
> "XY Event Layer" functionality (which is surprisingly fast:
> https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380176/are-xy-event-layers-optimized-indexed-on-the-fly).
>
> Source: [“Regarding the idea of indexing/returning a non-spatial datatype…”](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/comment/16838404/#Comment_16838404)